# Apache and Tomcat Integration to load balancing using mod_JK with parallel plesk

Tags: apache, tomcat, integration, load-balancing

"configuring Apache server to work as load balancer for tomcat server on cents 6".I bought a server which has httpd pre-installed with parallel plesk, I want this Apache to use as a load balancer for my java web server tomcat, using mod_jk.

server : dynamic cloud server, centos 6 64 bit
Apache Server : this is already installed with parallel plesk
Tomcat1 and Tomcat 2: Is locally installed and has following extra setup

```
    <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat1">
    <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost" jvmRoute="tomcat2">
```

Currently : example.com ---> direct to a page that is default and through Apache server. This is page which has come pre-configured, when we bought the server. I want example.com -----> to redirect to my web application deployed on tomcat1 and tomcat2. But it still shows same old page no redirection happens. When I try to follow the same steps on a plain linux machine with Apache 2.2 and tomcat, it works

I'm taking the following steps:

```
1. Download and copy mod_jk.so into /etc/httpd/module.
2. Edit /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf to add following lines

LoadModule jk_module modules/mod_jk.so

JkWorkersFile conf/workers.properties
JkLogFile logs/mod_jk.log
JkLogLevel info

JkMount / loadbalancer
JkMount /* loadbalancer

3. Create workers.properties

worker.list=loadbalancer

worker.tomcat1.port=8009
worker.tomcat1.host=localhost
worker.tomcat1.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat1.lbfactor=1

worker.tomcat2.port=8010
worker.tomcat2.host=localhost
worker.tomcat2.type=ajp13
worker.tomcat2.lbfactor=1

worker.loadbalancer.type=lb
worker.loadbalancer.balance_workers=tomcat1, tomcat2
worker.loadbalancer.method=Busyness

4. Restart tomcat and httpd.

5. Access : example.com : this still displays the old page, nothing is forwarded to tomcat.
```